# How do I return only text as a respond to Telegram inline query by Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to respond to an inline query but there is no response from my bot. However, Telegram returns `{"ok":true,"result":true}` as the HTTP response. Here's my Google Apps Script code:

```
var execute = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/";
function answerInlineQuery(id,text){
  var output = { 
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "answerInlineQuery",
      inline_query_id: id,
      result: [{
        type: "article",
        id: id,
        title: "This is a title",
        description: text,
        input_message_content: {
          message_text: text,
        },
      }]
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(execute,output);
}
```

How do I solve this? Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there something to do with the bot settings (BotFather)?

In case you need a demonstration of the problem, try the bot yourself by using an inline query (type `@ClearTheBot [something]` in any chat).
https://t.me/ClearTheBot

Comment: where are you expecting the *respond*?

Comment: What happens when you run `console.log(answerInlineQuery(id, text))`

Comment: @Bravo what do you mean by expecting the respond?

Comment: @joey I cant run the function from the editor because I have to respond as soon as the request is sent before the request timeout expired. But if you refer to putting the `console.log` as part of the main code, it's the same, nothing happens except the `{"ok":true,"result":true}` HTTP response

Comment: @ErsihFrans ok if you can get a response from calling this function by itself, then there should be nothing wrong with the function. The issue may be the trigger from the inline query

Comment: @joey the thing is other (sample) bot (not mine) can run well, just how do they do that? is it something with the code or the bot settings ([BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather))

Comment: you said *but there is no respond from my bot* so I asked *where are you expecting the respond* - because the code you posted doesn't look like there'd be a respond anywhere

Comment: @Bravo it's the ```UrlFetchApp```? _my bot_ refers to the Telegram bot when i enter an inline query

Comment: try the bot yourselves https://t.me/ClearTheBot

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly change `output.payload.results[0].id` to `1` and/or `JSON.stringify(output.payload.result)`

Comment: @idfurw The webhook has been set. Otherwise, I won't receive `{"ok":true,"result":true}` as HTTP response.

I can't use `getUpdates` method with a webhook set into the bot. But when I delete the webhook and run `getUpdates`, it returns nothing but `{"ok":true,"result":[]}`.

Here's the sample log of `e.postData.contents`:
`{"update_id":112514622,"inline_query":{"id":"5162892686567546320","from":{"id":"this is my id","is_bot":false,"first_name":"Ersih","last_name":"Frans","username":"this is username","language_code":"en"},"chat_type":"sender","query":"hello world","offset":""}}`

Comment: @idfurw you can try the bot yourself. It works well except the inline query part. https://t.me/ClearTheBot

Comment: @Blastfurnace Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: sorry for not giving any reply lately, I tried it and it still doesn't change anything